# How to implement apple-touch-icon to a site

Tags: theming

I'm trying to place an [apple-touch-icon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Device_support) on a site.  I have attempted to implement this via the following code block placed in `example_preprocess_node()`..

```
function example_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  ...

  $apple_touch = array(
    'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
    'href' => path_to_theme() . '/apple-touch-icon.png',
    'sizes' => '114x114'
  );

  drupal_add_html_head_link($apple_touch);

  ...

}
```

I cleared the caches and reloaded the page, but I'm not seeing the `<link.../>` line in my header at all.

Is this this right place to implement the apple-touch-icon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I enhanced @willtate code a little.
**Note**: If you need to create the icons quickly use this online generator: http://iconifier.net/

### Add the default icon

```
$apple_icon =  array(
  '#tag' => 'link',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'href' => path_to_theme() .'/apple-touch-icon.png',
    'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
  ),
); 

drupal_add_html_head($apple_icon, 'apple-touch-icon');
```

### Loop through to add various sizes

```
$apple_icon_sizes = array(57,72,114,144);

foreach($apple_icon_sizes as $size){
  $apple = array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'href' => path_to_theme().'/apple-touch-icon-'.$size.'x'.$size.'.png',
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon-precomposed',
      'sizes' => $size . 'x' . $size,
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($apple, 'apple-touch-icon-'.$size);
}
```

### HTML Output

```
<link sizes="57x57" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="sites/all/themes/yourtheme/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"></link>
<link sizes="72x72" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="sites/all/themes/yourtheme/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"></link>
<link sizes="114x114" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="sites/all/themes/yourtheme/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"></link>
<link sizes="144x144" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="sites/all/themes/yourtheme/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"></link>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="sites/all/themes/yourtheme/apple-touch-icon.png"></link>
```

Answer (score 4):

After some tinkering I've finally got it working:

```
function example_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  ...

  //regular apple-touch-icon
  $apple = array(
    '#tag' => 'link', // The #tag is the html tag - <link />
    '#attributes' => array( // Set up an array of attributes inside the tag
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'href' => path_to_theme() .'/apple-touch-icon.png',
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($apple, 'apple-touch');

  // 72x72 apple-touch-icon
  $apple = array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'href' => path_to_theme() . '/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png',
      'sizes' => '72x72',
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($apple, 'apple-touch-72');

  // 114x114 apple-touch-icon
  $apple = array(
    '#tag' => 'link',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
      'href' => path_to_theme() . '/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png',
      'sizes' => '114x114',
    ),
  );
  drupal_add_html_head($apple, 'apple-touch-114');

  ...

}
```

Note: I was forced to use [`drupal_add_html_head()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) here as [`drupal_add_html_head_link()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head_link/7) only allows for distinct `rel` values.

Comment: The other important thing is doing it from [`template_preprocess_html`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) and not the node pre-preprocess.